# Create DataFrame from list of rows, and Iterate Over it

Tags: python, pandas

NOTE - I asked this question assuming my issue was with the DataFrame constructor, but actually my issue was with iterrows()

I would like to create a pandas DataFrame from a list a rows, where each row is a list of values.  I have tried the following:

```
multigram_counts = [
    ["happy birthday", 23],
    ["used below", 10],
    ["frame for", 2]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(multigram_counts, columns = ["phrase", "count"])
df_iter = df.iterrows()
frow = df_iter.next()
self.assertEqual(frow['phrase'], "happy birthday")
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I fix this so that both arguments in my "assertEqual" function are indeed equal?  That is, I would like frow['phrase'] to equal "happy birthday".

Comment: Your code makes little sense, firstly post what your desired output is, secondly your created df has no values as lists but single str values, thirdly what is 'feat' column? It's nowhere in your code??

Comment: My desired value is in the assertEqual function, I assumed familiarity with unittesting.  Typo with phrase vs feat... thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df_iter` contains (index, row) as a tuple, to get the row only, try this:

```
f_index, frow = df_iter.next()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `frow` variable is a tuple and you are calling it as a dict, if I were you, I would debug it to know what is the value of `frow`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me, if you just want the first row then use `iloc`:

```
In [99]:

multigram_counts = [
    ["happy birthday", 23],
    ["used below", 10],
    ["frame for", 2]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(multigram_counts, columns = ["phrase", "count"])
​
df.iloc[0]['phrase'] == 'happy birthday'
Out[99]:
True
```

df looks like this:

```
In [100]:

df
Out[100]:
           phrase  count
0  happy birthday     23
1      used below     10
2       frame for      2
```